# Get the tags of a document in Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tags

I was wondering if there is a way to easily see the tags of a specific file in Subversion using the command line and/or TortoiseSVN.

Most version control system allow you to see easily access the tags/labels of a file. When using TortoiseSVN I can do this when I access the "Revision Graph". This however is a operation that takes around 44 minutes. I consider this very hard work just to know what tags have been created for the file. Is there another way to do it? Or is there no way to instantaneously access tag information.

Thanks,
Onno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical SVN layout looks like:

```
/trunk
/branches
/tags
```

Typically, all tags are committed to the /tags directory.

If you have a similar implementation, one solution is to:

1. open the TortoiseSVN Repo Browser
2. right-click on the "tags" directory and select "Show log"
3. type in the file you're interested in inside the search box at the top of the screen

At this point the Log will show you all tags that contain that file.

Comment: Yes this an option but this will also take a very long time. Too long for users familiar with other version control systems. They won't understand it takes 40 minutes or more to produce this essential information.